# Get JSON using Python and AsyncIO

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Not so long ago, I began to learn asyncio. And I ran into a problem. My code is not terminating. I can't figure it out. Help me please!

```
import signal
import sys
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import json

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
client = aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop)

async def get_json(client, url):
    async with client.get(url) as response:
        assert response.status == 200
        return await response.read()

async def get_reddit_cont(subreddit, client):
    data1 = await get_json(client, 'https://www.reddit.com/r/' + subreddit + '/top.json?sort=top&t=day&limit=50')

    jn = json.loads(data1.decode('utf-8'))

    print('DONE:', subreddit)

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    loop.stop()
    client.close()
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

for key in {'python':1, 'programming':2, 'compsci':3}:
    asyncio.ensure_future(get_reddit_cont(key, client))
loop.run_forever()
```

Result:

```
DONE: compsci  
DONE: programming  
DONE: python  
...
```

---

I tried to accomplish something, but the result was not stable.

```
future = []
for key in {'python':1, 'programming':2, 'compsci':3}:
    future=asyncio.ensure_future(get_reddit_cont(key, client))
loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

Result (1 tasks instead of 3):

```
DONE: compsci  
[Finished in 1.5s]
```

---

I solved my question in this way:

Added by:

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession () as a client:
```

AT:

```
async def get_reddit_cont (subreddit, client):
```

And:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    futures = [get_reddit_cont(subreddit,client) for subreddit in range(1,6)]
    result = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*futures))
```

But when the code is completed, I get the message:

```
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x034021F0>
[Finished in 1.0s]
```

I don't understand why this is happening.

But when I try to execute "for key" about 60 or more times, I get an error:

> ...
>   aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientOSError: [WinError 10054] Remote host forcibly terminated an existing connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies in your code. Here's the clue `loop.run_forever()`. So you will need to call `loop.stop()`. I would use a condition such as an `if` clause or using a `while` loop.

```
if we_have_what_we_need:
    signal_handler(signal, frame)
```

or

```
while we_dont_have_what_we_need:
    loop.forever()
```

The first will stop your code when the condition is met. The latter will keep going until the condition is met.

[UPDATE]

We can also use;

### (Python Docs)

```
loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

> Run until the future (an instance of Future) has completed.
>
> If the argument is a coroutine object it is implicitly scheduled to
>   run as a asyncio.Task.
>
> Return the Future’s result or raise its exception.

```
loop.run_forever()
```

> Run the event loop until stop() is called.

Comment: Yes, I understand that the matter is in it, but I don't understand how to fix it. :(

Comment: You need to call `loop.stop()`. I woul duse a condition such as an `if` clause or using a `while` loop. You can find it in the [python docs] (https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.stop)

Comment: @idrees The standard idiom is `run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(coroutine1(), coroutine2(), ...))`, which will complete once _all_ the coroutines complete, so you no longer have a need for `run_forever`. Brad's answer shows a variant when the number of coroutines is not known in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few suggested changes, with context in the comments.

Unless you really have a unique use-case, or are just experimenting for learning's sake, there probably shouldn't be a reason to use `signal` -- `asyncio` has top-level functions that let you decide when to close and terminate the event loop.

```
import asyncio
import logging
import sys

import aiohttp

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s:%(message)s')

URL = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/{subreddit}/top.json?sort=top&t=day&limit=50'


async def get_json(client: aiohttp.ClientSession, url: str) -> dict:
    # If you're going to be making repeated requests, use this
    # over .get(), which is just a wrapper around `.request()` and
    # involves an unneeded lookup
    async with client.request('GET', url) as response:

        # Raise if the response code is >= 400.
        # Some 200 codes may still be "ok".
        # You can also pass raise_for_status within
        # client.request().
        response.raise_for_status()

        # Let your code be fully async.  The call to json.loads()
        # is blocking and won't take full advantage.
        #
        # And it does largely the same thing you're doing now:
        # https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/76268e31630bb8615999ec40984706745f7f82d1/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py#L985
        j = await response.json()
        logging.info('DONE: got %s, size %s', url, j.__sizeof__())
        return j


async def get_reddit_cont(keys, **kwargs) -> list:
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(**kwargs) as session:
        # Use a single session as a context manager.
        # this enables connection pooling, which matters a lot when
        # you're only talking to one site
        tasks = []
        for key in keys:
            # create_task: Python 3.7+
            task = asyncio.create_task(
                get_json(session, URL.format(subreddit=key)))
            tasks.append(task)
        # The result of this will be a list of dictionaries
        # It will only return when all of your subreddits
        # have given you a response & been decoded
        #
        # To process greedily, use asyncio.as_completed()
        return await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    default = ('python', 'programming', 'compsci')
    keys = sys.argv[1:] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else default
    sys.exit(asyncio.run(get_reddit_cont(keys=keys)))
```

Output:

```
$ python3 asyncreddit.py 
2018-11-07 21:44:49,495:Using selector: KqueueSelector
2018-11-07 21:44:49,653:DONE: got https://www.reddit.com/r/compsci/top.json?sort=top&t=day&limit=50, size 216
2018-11-07 21:44:49,713:DONE: got https://www.reddit.com/r/python/top.json?sort=top&t=day&limit=50, size 216
2018-11-07 21:44:49,947:DONE: got https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/top.json?sort=top&t=day&limit=50, size 216
```

---

Edit: from your question:

> But when the code is completed, I get the message: `Unclosed client session`

This is because you need to `.close()` the `client` object, just as you would a file object.  You can do that two ways:

- Call it explicitly: `client.close()`.  It is safer to wrap this in a `try`/`finally` block to make sure that it's closed no matter what
- Or (easier way), use the client as an async context manager, as in this answer.  This means that, after the `async with` block is over, the session is automatically closed via its `.__aexit__()` method.

The [`connector`](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client_advanced.html#connectors) is the underlying `TCPConnector`, which is an attribute of the session.  It handles the connection pooling, and it's what ultimately is left open in your code.

Comment: In this case, how would you skip or ignore a result if any of the clients don't respond? For example, a timeout or a 404 error?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in this way:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import json

async def get_json(client, url):
    async with client.get(url) as response:
        assert response.status == 200
        return await response.read()

async def get_reddit_cont(subreddit):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as client:
        data1 = await get_json(client, 'https://www.reddit.com/r/' + subreddit + '/top.json?sort=top&t=day&limit=50')

        jn = json.loads(data1.decode('utf-8'))

        print('DONE:', subreddit)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    futures = [get_reddit_cont(subreddit) for subreddit in {'python':1, 'programming':2, 'compsci':3}]
    result = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*futures))
```